# angularjs model reload after item delete

Tags: angularjs

I'm pretty new in angularjs and I have no idea how do this.

```
<div class="userData" ng-repeat="user in users">
<div class="float"
    <img ng-click="deleteUser($event)" src="myurl">
</div>
<div class="userDiv"
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.active" ng-click="handleUserActive()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.text">
</div>
</div>
```

I need remove a item when the user click the img.
My model is:

```
$scope.users = [
{active: true, text: text}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
<img ng-click="deleteUser($index)" src="myurl">
```

And the method:

```
$scope.deleteUser = function(index) {
    $scope.users.splice(index, 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What tymeJV said, however, you want to pass the object as the parameter rather than the index like this:

```
<img ng-click="deleteUser(user)" src="myurl">

$scope.deleteUser = function(user) {
  var index = $scope.users.indexOf(user);
  $scope.users.splice(index, 1)
}
```

The reason why is the index can change if you do an orderBy on the ng-repeat.

See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/6a5zT/

Comment: ok, thanks, but now when i delete the user, the browser reload the page and the user is intact

Comment: Well, yeah, when the browser reloads, the app starts over.  You would have to store the records in a database or somewhere else as the central source of data.